# Django: File is only saved when created in admin page

Tags: python, django

I have a very odd problem:
When I create an object for my `Custom` model in the admin page everything works fine. However, when I fill in the same input in my custom Form in the website it does not work.

The problem is the `file` field: When I input a valid file in the form in the website, it is not saved and so I get a validation error (see clean() function below). Because there is no `self.file` even when I upload a file. In the admin page it works.

Where is the error?

Background:

Here is my `Custom` model:

```
# In my models.py
class Custom(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(max_length=45, upload_to=get_filepath, blank=True)
    file_info = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    ...

    def clean(self):
        if self.file_info and not self.file:
            raise ValidationError("...")
```

And here is my custom CreateView:

```
class CustomCreate(CreateView):
    model = Custom
    form_class = CustomForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.user = self.request.user
        self.object.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your problem is in the HTML.

Did you set the `enctype` in the form as this?

```
<form action="." method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

</form>
```

If you don't do this, the file will not work. This value is required when you are using forms that have a file upload control.

Comment: If i'm not using files and put enctype="multipart/form-data" in form, will that do something wrong or it will works correctly?